# Argument data type nvarchar is invalid for argument 3 of convert function in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, ssrs-2008, reportbuilder

I am having an issue with a parameter and the convert function when executing my query in Report Builder.
I am having the following in my code:

`CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), COALESCE(Status.POBDate, Status.[Sched Collection Date]),(@DateFormat)) AS [Collection Date]`
`,CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), Status.[Act Del Date],(@DateFormat)) AS [Delivery Date]`
[image]

The (@DateFormat) parametner has data type Integer and available values as per the bild below.
[image]

The funny thing is that I can run the query in SSMS without any problem, but when trying to apply some adjustments in Report Builder, and save the report, it is complaining about the invalind argument even though, the parament (@DateFormat) was not edited anyhow. The report worked perfect online and only after opening it in Report Builder it started to complain also when I do not apply any new adjustments.

Any idea what can be wrong and how I could solve it?
I have checked some ideas here on stackoverflow, but nothing worked out so far.

Tones of thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parameter type is text not integer and that causes the error.

You can verify it by casting the DateFormat parameter to INTEGER in your SQL code

```
 CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), COALESCE(Status.POBDate, Status.[Sched Collection Date]),CAST(@DateFormat AS INTEGER)) AS [Collection Date]
```

As a suggestion use the parameter to format the dates inside the report.

How to do it:

Remove conversion from your SQL code

In your parameter set it to text and as values set the date format string

For US `="dd/MM/yyyy"`

For UK `="MM/dd/yyyy"`

For your date fields set the format expression to `= Parameters!DateFormat.Value`

[image]